# Received an email from a Bulgarian address trying to extort money

Tags: email, ransomware, email-spoofing, scam

As the title says, I received an email from some Bulgarian email address saying that the sender has compromised my browser and thereby obtained control over my camera as well as gathering data on all my social media profiles. He threatens to send the pictures to relatives and colleagues if I don't transfer 400$ worth of BTC to his wallet.

I have three questions:

- How credible is this threat?
  Is it possible and easy enough to do this over a browser? I've taped over my camera since quite a while so that makes me additionally suspicious. Also, I recently registered a website with that email address and have been receiving a lot more spam since then.
- Can I find out who sent the mail?
  The email provider is from Bulgaria, but the header says
  `X-Originating-IP: [86.153.97.58]`, which seems to be from the UK. Can I somehow find out if this is a VPN address or the actual private one?
- The email says that I have 24hr after reading the mail, but also says that I shouldn't respond, because he's never going to use that mailbox again. Can I somehow find out if a read receipt has been sent to some address?

I should maybe add that this is not some kind of Nigerian romance scam or whatever. I have no clue who this person could be.

Email content:

> Sie wurden wecken sexuell vorlaptop-Bildschirm wenn Sie besuchten bzw.
>   besuchen Erwachsene Internet site yours palmtop-computer gefangen
>   Schadprogramm wegen Verletzlichkeit Ihre browser.
>
> Die bösartigen soft registriert alle Aktionen notebook und unter
>   anderen WLAN über Cookies der websites die besuchen.
>
> Und die key Vorteil von die benannte feindlich Programm, dass es ist
>   in der Lage Energie front-Kamera, selfie Kamera und entfernen alle
>   Telefonnummern von yours mail.
>
> gleichzeitig haben Benutzernamen yours box und
>   social-networking-Plattform.
>
> So ich besitzen video und snap-shots auf denen du beat the dummy und
>   nackt.
>
> falls nicht Wunsch, die content geben auf der Welt und verschickt alle
>   Ihre Kumpels Familienangehörige I vorschlagen die Erfolg Lösung.
>
> Sie muss liefern Versand mine Bitcoin Nummer
>   1Cco1u33PEuAPuShZwqJRrZ4r1oQZHpop9 400 Vereinigten states dollar in
>   BTC.
>
> Nach Erhalt das Geld ich werde beseitigen kompromittierende Bild und
>   Sie sollte nie wieder hören etwa diese unangenehme situation.
>
> Sonst falls ich glaube nicht, erhalten Sie das cash in 24 Stunden nach
>   öffnen dieser E-mail ich werde Versand diese verschmutztSchmutz - Sie
>   yours eng Verwandte Menschen und arbeitet und auch social media für
>   Allgemeine Schätzung von yours Aktionen.
>
> P. S. Meine Deutsch wird nicht weit von gut da its nicht meine
>   Muttersprache dennoch Sie kann zu verstehen was ich noch sagen möchte.
>
> Werden, so dass die Art und und machen keine Antwort mailing-box ich
>   darf nie verwenden, um es wieder.
>
> ------------------------------------- Mail.BG: Безплатен e-mail адрес. Най-добрите характеристики на българския пазар - 30 GB пощенска кутия,
>   1 GB прикрепен файл, безплатен POP3, мобилна версия и други.

Comment: Can you post full email?

Comment: julie.stokes1981@mail.bg

Comment: I meant the content of mail...

Comment: It's in **very** garbled German, but I'll add it.

Comment: Just respond him with this GIF -> https://media2.giphy.com/media/1LnQKc4eh8BP2/200w.gif

Comment: Hehe, thanks I'll use that. Still, is it possible to find out if the IP is from a VPN or private? I did a whois lookup, but it doesn't really tell me much.

Comment: As someone who can speak german, ignore this nonsense. If there is someone intelligent enough to hack your computer to get money, getting a grammatically correct demand from somewhere should be possible too.

Comment: Can you translate or partially translate it for those of us who don't speak German?

Comment: @forest I tried to make at least half as much errors as the original text has ... https://pastebin.com/SvRpFunA

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be fake ransom email...

> The Fake Threat Emails are poorly written; sent en Masse
>
> Fake ransomware racketeering is on the rise.
>
> The emails demanding Bitcoin are usually authored in poor English and
>   often contain threats to leak private information if the Bitcoin
>   ransom is not paid.
>
> These Bitcoin extortionists lie to their victims that they possess
>   sensitive information which, when leaked, would destroy reputations.

https://darkwebnews.com/bitcoin/fake-email-bitcoin-ransom/