# I received an phishing email from myself

Tags: email, phishing, email-spoofing, scam

So today when I was checking my spam folder on my outlook account, I noticed I had received an email from my own address.
The email looks like a typical scam:

- Claims to have installed a RAT on my system
- Claims to have footage of me pleasuring myself
- Demands that I pay him money with the cryptocurrency DASH

According to haveibeenpwned, my email was found on the July 2018 Animoto breach.
I have never used this site. I have used a similar service called 'PowToon', but as far as I can tell, they aren't related.

I have already:

- Changed the password of my Microsoft account (and made sure 2FA is still active)
- Made sure there isn't any suspicious devices or login activity registered
- Ran a virus scan on my system (Nothing found)

At this point, I'm pretty sure this is just a spoofed email address, but I want to guarantee everything is alright.
This is the header of the email:
https://pastebin.com/LD92Y3m2
Am I safe? What other precautions should I take?

Comment: Use a password manager. Always only use completely random passwords that are never reused on any other sites.  As far as if you're safe? As long as you're not reusing passwords, as safe as anyone else.  (Also pretty sure this is a duplicate...)

Comment: This is a common scam.  Personally I get about 1-2 of these a week in my spam box.  Ignore it and don't give it another thought.

Comment: You can see in the headers where the SPF check soft-failed, "Authentication-Results: spf=softfail (sender IP is 179.6.55.31)" and just a few lines below that, "hotmail.com discourages use of 179.6.55.31 as permitted sender".

Comment: It's weird how Outlook still let the email get into my Mailbox even though the headers were apparently incorrect. It was marked as spam but I still got very paranoid receiving a message from my own address when I didn't write any. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Received an email from a Bulgarian address trying to extort money](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185799/received-an-email-from-a-bulgarian-address-trying-to-extort-money), [Email from a hacker with my password](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201176/), [Should I be worried by an email which said my account was under attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206319/)

Comment: Do you pleasure yourself in front of your computer?  If not, then you're safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it look like ...

> Good day.
>   I excuse for my English, I am from China.
>   I put the malicious program on your OS.
>   Then all your confidential info appertains to me. Additionally I received a little bit more compromising evidence.
>   The most important evidence that I stole- its a record with your wanking.
>    I set malicious software on a porn site and after you loaded it. The moment you picked the video and tapped on a play, my malicious software immediately downloaded on your OS.
>   First of all, your web cam started working, then my software captured your screen. In next few days my malware grabbed all your social and email contacts.
>   If you wish to erase  the videotape- transfer me 295 usd in BTC(cryptocurrency).
>   I provide you my Btc address - 12caGmborZYaWM5hc26b3ueg19XD1XGibh 
>   You have 30 h. from this moment. If I get transfer I will eliminate the videotape forever. Otherwise I will send the record to all your contacts.

If yes this is a indeed a typical scam.

No any personal information is stolen. Attackers often speak about countries that are known for hacking at a big scale (China, Russia etc) just for psy reasons. And they hope to get money out of it with using manipulating words like 'We have X of you' to get the attention of the victim and when they receive something, later you will get a second email where is stated that you'd been recorded in another video because they know they targeted the right person.

(The example is real though)

Comment: I wasn't really worried about the scammer having recordings of me(since this computer doesn't even have a webcam), what worried me was him supposedly having access to my email account (looked pretty convincing since it was coming from my own address). Thanks!